# iOS Animation: animation stopped inovoke immediately

Tags: ios, swift, animation, rotation, layer

I want to implement a 3D roration on a door Image on a layer, but it does not work.
I found the animation stoped the function invoke immediately at start. So I think this is the reason why animation does not work.

Below is my **code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let doorLayer = CALayer()
    doorLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 128, height: 256)
    doorLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 150 - 64, y: 150)
    doorLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    doorLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "door")?.cgImage
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(doorLayer)

    var perspective = CATransform3DIdentity
    perspective.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0
    self.view.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective

    let animation = CABasicAnimation()
    animation.keyPath = "transform.rotation.y"
    animation.toValue = -Double.pi/2
    animation.duration = 2.0
    animation.repeatCount = 5
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.delegate = self
    doorLayer.add(animation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")

}
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    print(#function)
}
```

When the View shows, the message shows immediately.
How shall I do ?

Comment: Try animation in view did appear

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya thank you, It works in view will appear function